# Preventing parameter expansion multiple times

Tags: shell, scripting, parameter

I have a code that is writing a script which is writing another script:

```
    cat > step1.sh <<-EOF  
        *other commands*  
            cat > step2.sh <<-EOF4 
                if [ -f PM.log ]; then
                    awk '/testphrase/{ f=1;r=""; next }f && /testphrase2/{f=0}f{ r=(r=="")? $0: r RS $0 }END{ print r }' PM.log > tmp1.log
                    checkfree=($(cat tmp1.log))
                    wait 
                    sed -i '$ d' tmp${mold}.log
                    wait
                fi
        EOF4
        qsub step2.sh
EOF
qsub step1.sh
```

I am trying to prevent parameter expansion with the "$0" in line 5 of the code as well as with line 6 of the code ($(cat tmp1.log)).
I am aware that using "\" before the $ would prevent the parameter expansion once:

```
\$0
```

However, because this script is written by another script, I don't know how to manipulate to prevent double and triple expansions as each script is being written.

I also know that you can edit the end of file token but there are other parameters (such as mold in line 8) within the file that I DO want to expand so I can't do that either.

How can I stop these particular terms from being expanded every time?

Comment: It looks as if `EOF4` is the ending of an internal here-document, but I can't see where that here-document starts...

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the end of line token does this. Quote it in your first line:

```
cat > run1.sh <<-"EOF"
```

Comment: I can't do this because there are other parameters in the script that I DO want to expand. Quoting the end of line token would prevent all the expansions.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example script (all indentations are literal tabs):

```
#!/bin/sh

var='hello'

cat >script1.sh <<-END_SCRIPT1
        #!/bin/sh
        echo 'This is script1 ($var)'
        printf '\$0 is "%s"\n' "\$0"

        cat >script2.sh <<END_SCRIPT2
                #!/bin/sh
                echo 'This is script2 ($var)'
                printf '\\\$0 is "%s"\n' "\\\$0"
        END_SCRIPT2
END_SCRIPT1
```

In the outer here-document, we need to escape the `$` in `"$0"` as `"\$0"` to not have it expanded by the script writing the document.

To be able to write the inner here-document, we need to make sure that the outer here-document is writing `"\$0"`.  The backslash needs to be escaped as `\\`, which turns the string into `"\\\$0"`.

The script above writes `script1.sh` as

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'This is script2 (hello)'
printf '\$0 is "%s"\n' "\$0"
END_SCRIPT2
printf '$0 is "%s"\n' "$0"
```

Running this outputs

```
This is script1 (hello)
$0 is "script1.sh"
```

... and `script2.sh` is created:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'This is script2 (hello)'
printf '$0 is "%s"\n' "$0"
```

---

Notice that the inner here-document is created using `<<END_SCRIPT2`, not `<<-END_SCRIPT2`.  Any leading tabs will be eaten up when the outer here-document is created (as evident when looking at `script1.sh`).

---

As an aside, you don't need the two calls to `wait` in your code since you don't seem to run any background processes.

Your `awk` code is also faulty as the `f && /testphrase2/` condition would never be true.  If `/testphrase/` matches, then `next` is executed, forcing the code to continue with the next line of input. If `/testphrase/` does not match, then `/testphrase2/` won't match either.

Your could try this instead:

```
awk '!f && /testphrase/  { f = 1; r = "" }
     f  && /testphrase2/ { f = 0 }
     f                   { r = (r == "" ? $0 : r RS $0) }
     END                 { print r }'
```